# Please undelete this answer

Tags: support, deleted-answer

Please consider undeleting the following answer:
https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/48977/14721

I have addressed the valid issue which was the reason for deleting the answer. As written, the answer did not directly answer the question. I've edited the answer to directly answer the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Only a moderator can undelete an answer that was deleted by a moderator, and the best way to get a moderator's attention is to *flag* the answer.  You can do so by clicking the "flag" link on your answer:

[image: Click flag link]

Be sure to explain why you think your answer is now satisfactory, as the moderator who reviews your flag will take that into consideration:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have flagged the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Nathan is correct that flagging is the right way to request an undelete. However meta is the right place to have a discussion about it, so I'm actually glad this is here.

> Hello. I flagged this post as "not an answer" because you don't compare the Steet Bible and the KJV, but instead give your opinion about another version, which is not what the OP asked.

I reviewed the post in question and I don't think the core issue as pointed out in thes comment has been addressed. You made it a nicer post, but it's answering the wrong question. Seriously the *only* part of the post that answers the question is the first two lines. After that, none of that stuff belongs under this question. In fact, the only sort of question where that answer would be appropriate would be inappropriate for this site as it would be purely opinion based¹.

The question just doesn't call for a run down on what translations you think are good for whatever reason. If everybody did that there would be 75 answers to this question and no clear way to determine which were more useful. Instead the question is about one specific translation. You started out the answer stating your opinion on that translation, but you didn't back it up with anything at all. If the post was just the first paragraph, it would at least answer the question but given the lack of either explanation or references I don't think I would delete it even then.

¹ <sub>Honestly some of the fault here  lies with the original question as it is boarder-line itself, but even if we do decide to leave the question open that shouldn't be an excuse to dump opinion based answers on it. If people can't help themselves, then the question should probably be closed until it is more clearly scope.</sub>

Comment: Fair enough. I've removed all references to the suggested English translation, and left only the part that most directly answers the question. Thank you for taking your time to clarify your position and to help keep C.SE  on track.